# Почему при установке PIL появляется эта ошибка

Tags: pil

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Потому что пакета PIL не существует

Answer (score 0):

Разработка библиотеки PIL прекращена и более не поддерживается. Сейчас используется Pillow.

```
pip install Pillow
```